# xml add photo with entity

Tags: xml, image, xslt, entity

I want to add photos in xml with entities, but I'm don't know how to call them in the xsl file

this is the xml code:

```
<!DOCTYPE cookbook [
  <!NOTATION JPG SYSTEM "image/jpeg">
  <!ENTITY pizza SYSTEM "images/1.jpg" NDATA JPG>
]>

<cookbook>
  <recipe id="1" authorID="1" region="southwest">
    <picture>
      <image href="pizza"/>
    </picture>
  </recipe>
</cookbook>
```

and in the xsl I have the following:

```
<images>
  <xsl:for-each select="picture/image">
    <img src="href"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</images>
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe this is of help: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/03/14/trxml10.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `unparsed-entity-uri()`...

```
<img src="{unparsed-entity-uri(@href)}"/>
```